# How can I drag and drop custom objects between ListViews in UWP apps?

Tags: listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'd like to drag and drop custom objects between my `ListView`s in an UWP app. The `ListView`s contain `ListViewItem`s which are based on a custom object.

When I try to implement the required functionality, I seem to be bound to the choices provided by the `StandardDataFormats` class. None of them seems to be right for what I'd like to do, and when I try something like

```
private void ListViewOne_DragItemsStarting( object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e )
{
    e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
    e.Data.SetData( StandardDataFormats.StorageItems, ListViewOne.Items.First() );
}
```

I get a `COMException`, telling me that `StorageItem` objects cannot be created from the element being passed.

Trying to use different strings as a parameter to the `SetData` method throw an exception saying that the data type of the value is not being supported by the DataPackage element:

```
e.Data.SetData( "Custom", ListViewOne.Items.First() );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StandardDataFormats.StorageItems` is reserved for when you are dragging files from explorer in your app. That's why you're getting a COM exception when you try to set it - it's an unsupported value for that format.

Since you are trying to move objects inside your app, you don't need to send the whole object in the payload, you just need to send a unique identifier in a `StandardDataFormats.Text` payload.

[Here's](http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2015/8/23/drag-and-drop-in-uwp) a good example for how to achieve that.